# how to tell if a string is base64 or not

Tags: python, jython, base64, mime

I have many emails coming in from different sources.
they all have attachments, many of them have attachment names in chinese, so these
names are converted to base64 by their email clients.

When I receive these emails, I wish to decode the name. but there are other names which are
not base64. How can I differentiate whether a string is base64 or not, using the **jython** programming language?

Ie.

First attachment:

```
------=_NextPart_000_0091_01C940CC.EF5AC860
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;
 name="Copy of Book1.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="Copy of Book1.xls"
```

second attachment:

```
------=_NextPart_000_0091_01C940CC.EF5AC860
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;
 name="=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?="
```

Please note both "**Content-Transfer-Encoding**" have base64

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Please note both `Content-Transfer-Encoding` have base64

Not relevant in this case, the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` only applies to the body payload, not to the headers.

```
=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?=
```

That's an **RFC2047**-encoded header atom. The stdlib function to decode it is `email.header.decode_header`. It still needs a little post-processing to interpret the outcome of that function though:

```
import email.header
x= '=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?='
try:
    name= u''.join([
        unicode(b, e or 'ascii') for b, e in email.header.decode_header(x)
    ])
except email.Errors.HeaderParseError:
    pass # leave name as it was
```

However...

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;
 name="=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?="
```

This is simply wrong. What mailer created it? RFC2047 encoding can only happen in atoms, and a quoted-string is not an atom. RFC2047 §5 explicitly denies this:

> - An 'encoded-word' MUST NOT appear within a 'quoted-string'.

The accepted way to encode parameter headers when long string or Unicode characters are present is **RFC2231**, which is a whole new bag of hurt. But you should be using a standard mail-parsing library which will cope with that for you.

So, you could detect the `'=?'` in filename parameters if you want, and try to decode it via RFC2047. However, the strictly-speaking-correct thing to do is to take the mailer at its word and really call the file `=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?=`!

Comment: I tried just calling the attachment just by ‘=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?=’ but unfortuntely it just falls apart and complains bitterly, I have no idea why, maybe looking into that complaining would solve the problem faster, thanks bobince appreciate it

Comment: What complains and when? The OS will probably get upset if you try to actually save a file with that name, sure, but any time you take a filename from user input you'll need some very strict filtering to keep dangerous characters out - best to only allow [a-zA-Z0-9_] (and catch an empty string too).

Comment: & I'd be surprised if Outlook created this, it is very malformed even by Microsoft standards! :-)

Comment: +1 for the python implementation and all the additional info. Cheers!

Comment: Also I actually need to know what type of file it is ie .xls or .doc so I do need to decode the filename in order to correctly process the attachment, but as above, seems gb2312 is not supported in jython, know any roundabouts?

Comment: I decide this was good enough:  
name = u''.join([b for b, e in email.Header.decode_header(name)])  
with a filename like this ¸±±¾hen¸±±¾g.xls at least I have the ext! thanks for you help!

Comment: it was outlook here is the header 'X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 11'

Comment: Ah, yes, Jython still doesn't have CJKCodecs (built into CPython since 2.4). You might be able to get access to GB through a java.nio.charset.Charset - JRE does not always install the East Asian codecs, but JDK should.

Comment: headache bobince, but thanks for the advice! endusers dont need to see the filename, and all that is needed is the .ext

Comment: It's not fair to blame Outlook, though. Here is what Thunderbird produces (3.0b4):

--------------000908030900000708050403
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 name="2009 09 24 =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Einf=FChrung_der_elektronischen_Signatur_?=
 =?ISO-8859-1?Q?und_Verschl=FCsselung_von_EDIFACT-Nachrichten=2Epdf?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename*0*=ISO-8859-1''%32%30%30%39%20%30%39%20%32%34%20%45%69%6E%66%FC;
 filename*1*=%68%72%75%6E%67%20%64%65%72%20%65%6C%65%6B%74%72%6F%6E%69%73;
<...> too long for comment

Answer (score 21):

The header value tells you this:

```
=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?=

"=?"     introduces an encoded value
"gb2312" denotes the character encoding of the original value
"B"      denotes that B-encoding (equal to Base64) was used (the alternative 
         is "Q", which refers to something close to quoted-printable)
"?"      functions as a separator
"uLG..." is the actual value, encoded using the encoding specified before
"?="     ends the encoded value
```

So splitting on "?" actually gets you this (JSON notation)

```
["=", "gb2312", "B", "uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==", "="]
```

In the resulting array, if "B" is on position 2, you face a base-64 encoded string on position 3. Once you decoded it, be sure to pay attention to the encoding on position 1, probably it would be best to convert the whole thing to UTF-8 using that info.

Comment: nice, counting starting from 0

Comment: Is this answer based on authorative documentation?

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for that clear answer Tomalak! It is difficult to decide who gets the right answer between you and bobince, you gave a clear understanding into the nature of the encoding. But I will try the email.header.decode_header thing, that just did it for me! I still upped you though!

Answer (score 7):

@gnud, @edg - Unless I misunderstand, he's asking about the filename, not the file content
@setori - the Content-Trasfer-Encoding is telling you how the CONTENT of the file is encoded, not the "filename".

I'm not an expert, but this part here in the filename is telling him about the characters that follow:

=?gb2312?B?

I'm looking for the documentation in the RFCs... Ah! here it is: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047

The RFC says:

***Generally, an "encoded-word" is a sequence of printable ASCII characters that begins with "=?", ends with "?=", and has two "?"s in between.***

Something else to look at is the code in SharpMimeTools, a MIME parser (in C#) that I use in my [bug tracking](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) app, [BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html)

Comment: correct im asking after the filename not the content, i have never had trouble with that, even though it has chinese characters in it. as it is all base64

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way than bobince’s method to handle the output of `decode_header`. I found it here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/email-sig/2007-March/000332.html

```
name = unicode(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you parse the email header into a dictionary. And then you check if Content-Transfer-Encoding is set, and if it = "base64" or "base-64".

Answer (score 0):

Question: """Also I actually need to know what type of file it is ie .xls or .doc so I do need to decode the filename in order to correctly process the attachment, but as above, seems gb2312 is not supported in jython, know any roundabouts?"""

Data:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;
 name="=?gb2312?B?uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==?="
```

Observations:

(1) The first line indicates Microsoft Excel, so `.xls` is looking better than `.doc`

(2)

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode("uLGxvmhlbrixsb5nLnhscw==")
'\xb8\xb1\xb1\xbehen\xb8\xb1\xb1\xbeg.xls'
>>>
```

(a) The extension appears to be `.xls` -- no need for a `gb2312` codec
(b) If you want a file-system-safe file name, you could use the "-_" variant of base64 OR you could percent-encode it
(c) For what it's worth, the file name is `XYhenXYg.xls` where X and Y are 2 Chinese characters that together mean "copy" and the remainder are literal ASCII characters.